# Ubuntu keeps crashing on Huawei Matebook D (Ryzen 5 2500u)

Tags: 18.04, 19.04, crash, huawei

I have seen a few posts on here about the Matebook D and have tried a couple of the solutions but so far nothing seems to have worked. I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 (18.04 until a week ago). I've updated the kernel to 5.3.7. Through my windows partition I've ensured that the BIOS is updated (1.22 I believe). I still find that on chromium browser it will freeze anywhere from 1 minute to 1 day. It seems to happen more often on JS-heavy websites which involve a lot of content auto-loading eg. facebook. In the logs I've got:

```
09:49:50 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
09:49:50 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
09:49:46 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
09:49:19 systemd: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
09:49:17 dhclient: Timeout too large reducing to: 2147483646 (TIME_MAX - 1)
09:49:16 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
09:49:16 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
09:49:12 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
09:49:12 kernel: kvm: disabled by bios
09:49:11 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1.
09:49:11 kernel: kvm: disabled by bios
09:49:11 kernel: kfd kfd: device 1002:15dd NOT added due to errors
09:49:11 kernel: kvm: disabled by bios
09:49:11 kernel: snd_pci_acp3x 0000:02:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode : 1
09:49:11 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
09:49:11 kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
09:49:11 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
09:49:11 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x8f7a6000-0x8f7a9fff]
09:49:11 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
09:49:11 kernel: AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to stop this happening? Let me know if I need to provide any more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a ton of issues on IOMMU with the ryzen processors. I also faced 
it. Try to add the following option to /etc/default/grub at line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

```
iommu=soft
```

Then run

```
$> sudo update-grub
```

Finally reboot

Comment: thanks for your response. Just to be clear the line already reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` so you're saying add rather than replace right:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=soft"` ?

Comment: So far this seems to have worked! Just going to give it to the end of the day before I give it a thumbs up

Comment: In the end I used a combination of `iommu=soft` and `processor.max_cstate=1`, and upgraded to 19.10. This seems to have fixed it. So thanks to both answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try add to kernel boot options something like this:

```
processor.max_cstate=1 // or 5
```

Comment: would this also mean editing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`  in the grub file?